# Getting HandlerMethod's parameters names in an interceptor

Tags: java, spring, rest, reflection

I've defined a method, getuserData:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myRestApi",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, MyClass1> getUserData(@RequestParam(value = "xyz1",
required = false) List<String> input1,
        @RequestParam(value = "xyz2",
        required = true) String input2,
        @RequestParam(value = "xyz3",
        required = false,
        defaultValue = "COMPLETE") MyClass2 input3)
                throws Exception
```

And an interceptor for the corresponding request in a class extending HandlerInterceptorAdapter.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    String method = request.getMethod();
    String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();

    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {

        ArrayList<String> listOfParamNamesInMethodSignature = new ArrayList<>();
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = ((HandlerMethod) handler);
        for (MethodParameter param : handlerMethod.getMethodParameters()) {
            String name = param.getParameterName();
            listOfParamNamesInMethodSignature.add(param.getParameterName());
        }

        List<String> listOfParamNamesInRequest1 = new ArrayList<String>(request.getParameterMap().keySet());

        if(listOfParamNamesInRequest1 != null && listOfParamNamesInMethodSignature.containsAll(listOfParamNamesInRequest1))
            return true;
    }
}
```

Now if someone calls an API, for eg:  /myRestApi?xyz1=fname,lname&xyz2=address

Then in the handler I want to get the list of parameter names passed in the API along with the list of parameter names in the Handler Method which is ultimately going to serve the API request.

Now given this code, I'm able to get the parameter names (xyz1, xyz2) passed in the API request but am not able to get the names of the parameters (xyz1, xyz2, xyz3) present in the Handlermethod, getUserData() in the interceptor. Only information about the method that I'm getting in the interceptor is its name, getUserData !!

Could you please help me in figuring out if I'm missing anything here ??

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. The handler parameter names are exactly what’s present in the request - what else is there to find out?

Comment: The HandlerMethod has a total of 3 parameters and the API request has only two parameters in it. In fact a user can call the API by passing just one parameter, because rest two are optional.
So irrespective of the API call, I want to get the names of all the three parameters present in the method getUserData(), viz. xyz1, xyz2, xyz3.

Comment: So, you want to find the names of the request param annotations regardless of the request, even though you already know the names?

Comment: Ok .... I'll try to summarize ... I want two list..... one from the API request and another from the HandlerMethod. One can also take it like..... I don't care about info. present in the API call, I want the list of parameter names present in the method signature.

Comment: This interceptor will work for all the request mappings and so I want to generalize the things..... The goal here is to find out if passed parameter name in the API request matches with the parameter names present in the method signature. If not, then instead of ignoring (default behaviour in spring), I want to respond with BAD_REQUEST.

Comment: You're barking the wrong tree. If request params don't match the handler signature, Spring returns a 404 without you having to do anything. If the request does match but there are unknown params, those are ignored. Acc. to [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), 400 status code code indicates "malformed syntax", which is certainly not true for additional params. If I were you, I'd do what you're saying only if I were paid by the hour, and had nothing better to do.

Comment: You got me this time when you said "If the request does match but there are unknown params, those are ignored".... Lets say if someone wants to filter the response by passing xyz1=Maddy..... but instead of this if his url consists of xz1=Maddy (Here, "y" is missing)..... then he will get the whole result without any filter..... I don't want this kind of behaviour for my API and reveal everything present in DB !!
So could you please respond with any solution to this kind of problem ??

Comment: You’re not designing a spellchecker. This kinda what if argument is plain nonsense; no one makes a HTTP call by making up URLs on the fly. Most clients have an already known URL where they replace the placeholders at runtime. The only exception is HATEOAS but I’ll bet my last dime that that’s not what you’ve as clients. Enuf said.